# How to detect network going down event in feathersjs client

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am working on a nodejs project. The backend is using `featuresjs` and the client side is using `feather-client` js which is served by the backend. The backend code is shown as below:

```
app
  .use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use('/', serveStatic(app.get('public')))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(
    swagger({
      docsPath: '/docs',
      uiIndex: path.join(__dirname, '../public/docs.html'),
      info: {
        title: process.env.npm_package_fullName,
        description: process.env.npm_package_description,
      },
    }),
  )
  .configure(
    primus(
      {
        transformer: 'websockets',
        timeout: false,
      },
      (primus) => {
        primus.library();
        primus.save(path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/primus.js'));
      },
    ),
  )
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware);
```

it works fine if the network is available on the host. But if the network going down and UI try to send a request to backend, that request will be cached in UI side. The request will be sent to backend when the network is going back online. Interesting thing is that this happens when my UI and backend running on the same machine and using `localhost` to connect each other. I don't understand why the network issue impacts `localhost` connection.

In addition, I wonder how I can detect the network unavailable in featuresjs client side. I want to show an error message to user if it is not availabe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it in by listening to the underneath `socket` events - see in the code:

```
/* Show the user that we are going to connect to the server.
 * Message box will disappear after initial state is read. */
coverBox.show("Connecting ...");

var socketio = io();

socketio.on("reconnecting", function(delay, attempt) {
    coverBox.show("Disconnected ... trying to reconnect.");
});

socketio.on("reconnect", function() {
    coverBox.hide();
});

socketio.on("reconnect_failed", function() {
    socketio.socket.reconnect();
});

var feathersApp = feathers()
    .configure(feathers.hooks())
    .configure(feathers.socketio(socketio))
    .configure(feathers.authentication({ storage: window.localStorate }));
```